# How do i create an int variable with space in mql5?

Tags: mql5

I saw an indicator in ex5 format. I wanted to use the indicator in an EA. One of the processes is to write the indicator input parameter as it is inside my EA. The problem am having now is the int variable is having space in between. Example, input int Calc Bars = 500; that is what the indicator is having. putting it in my EA, Bars is a mql5 code, mql5 is seeing Calc Bars as two different words. How do I overcome this problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is the variable name? Variable names cannot include spaces. This is most likely the comment after the input variable definition. In the imported EA, the corresponding source code most likely looked like this:

```
input int cBars = 500;  // Calc Bars
```

I spelled it `cBars`, but it could be any name. You should make sure you find out the name of the input variable. There should be some documentation along with the ex5 file.